# How can I set file creation times in ZFS?

Tags: filesystems, timestamp, freebsd, inode, zfs

I've just got a NAS running ZFS and I'd like to preserve creation times when transferring files into it.  Both linux/ext4 (where the data is now) and zfs store creation time or birth time. In the case of zfs it's even reported by  the stat command.  But I haven't been able to figure out how I can set the creation time of a file so it mirrors the creation time in the original file system.  Unlike an ext4->ext4 transfer where I can feed debugfs a script to set the file creation times.

Is there a tool similar to debugfs for ZFS?

PS. To explain better:

- I have a USB drive attached to a Ubuntu 14.04 laptop.  It holds  a file system where I care about the creation date (birth date) of the individual files. I consult these creation timestamps often using a script based on debugfs, which reports it as crtime.
- I want to move the data to a NAS box running ZFS, but the methods I know (scp -p -r, rsync -a, and tar, among others I've tried) preserve the modification time but not the creation time.
- If I were moving to another ext4 file system I would solve the problem using the fantastic tool `debugfs`.  Specifically I can make a list of  (filename, crtime) pairs on the source fs (file system), then use `debugfs -w` on the target fs to read a script with lines of the form

  `set_inode_field filename crtime <value>`

I've tested this and it works just fine.

- But my  target fs  is not ext4 but ZFS and although `debugfs` runs on the target machine, it is entirely useless there.  It doesn't even recognize the fs.  Another debug tool that lets you alter timestamps by editing an inode directly is  fsdb; it too runs on the target machine, but again I can't seem to get it to recognize a ZFS file system.
- I'm told by the folks who sold me the NAS box that debugfs and fsdb are not meant for ZFS filesystems, but they haven't been able to come up with an equivalent.  So, after much googling and trying out things I finally decided to post a question here today, hoping someone might have the answer.

I'm surprised at how hard this is turning out to be. The question of how to replicate a dataset so all timestamps are identical seems quite natural from an archival point of view.

Comment: Don't see why this doesn't belong on server fault.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks. Are you suggesting I should move the question to serverfault?  If so, should I wait for the bounty period to run out here and delete the question and post it on serverfault?  I'm not a professional sysadmin, I just manage the 5 linux boxes in my household, so posting questions there is new territory for me.

Comment: If you can delete it now, I'd suggest doing so. (I expect you're attracting downvotes in lieu of close votes, since folks can't vote to close while there is a bounty.) Then try posting over there; your question seems well formulated, and the subject should be relevant to their interests.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying the downvotes are because the question is offtopic. which I wouldn't have guessed from many other questions asked.  

At other SE sites I belong to someone downvoting a question would leave a comment to explain why, unless the question is complete garbage. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For what it's worth if the solution will involve scripting, stackoverflow is still suitable place to post it. +1

Comment: Does `rsync -t` preserve `crtime` fields? I'm guessing that `rsync -a` is the flag for archival preservation of everything  possible (like `pax -pe`) so it's likely you explored this path.

Comment: I wish.  The manual page says "-t:         preserve modification times".  Yes, -a is for archive, and it preserves mtime (not ctime, atime or crtime) plus permissions and hierarchy.  It's super convenient.

Comment: Can the filesystem be exported as a network share where `crtime` field is supported and then simply copied over to FreeBSD and ZFS?  ... hmm oops wait: it doesn't seem that FreeBSD utilities (`cp`, `tar`, *etc.*) support preserving `crtime`.

Comment: Hi Silvio. Any luck resolving this?   I assume you commented on this post recently: http://cmynhier.blogspot.sk/2007/01/zfs-stores-file-creation-time.html or else you've been trying to solve this for a long time :-)  It might be useful to post a question to the [FreeBSD filesystem mailing list](https://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-fs) about this. Even though the issue appears to be more at the level of user space tool support for preserving the field rather than the file system  itself, there could be people there who can suggest workarounds.

Comment: Yes, that comment on Chad Mynhier's blog was mine; unfortunately  no reply. If I find the solution I'll definitely post it here.  I had to take time off from this search to attend to urgent projects.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, neither `fsdb` nor `debugfs` are likely to be suitable for use with ZFS. What you might need to do instead is find an archive format that will the preserve `crtime` field that presumably is already set for the files on your fileserver. If there is a version of [`pax`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/man/pax.1.html) or another archiving tool for your system it may be able to do this (*cf.* the `-pe` "preserve everything" flag for `pax` which it seems in current versions does ***not*** preserve "everything" - *viz.* it does not preserve `crtime`/birth_time). You will likely have more success finding an archiving application that is "`crtime` aware" than trying set the creation times by hacking on the ZFS based FreeBSD system with what are likely to be rudimentary tools.

You may be able to find more advanced tools on [OpenSolaris](http://www.opensolaris.org) based systems like [Illumos](http://www.illumos.org) or [SmartOS](http://www.smartos.org) (*e.g.* [`mdb`](http://www.illumos.org/man/1/mdb)). Whether it would be possible to transfer your data to a ZFS dataset on one of those platforms and then, combining the tools they have with, say, [`dtrace`](http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/DTrace) in order to rewrite the `crtime` fields is more of a theoretical question. If it worked then you could export the pool and its datasets to FreeBSD - exporting a pool does seem to preserve the `crtime` time stamps. If you *are* able to preserve `crtime` while dumping your ext4 filesystem to a [ZFSonLinux](http://zfsonlinux.org/) dataset *on the same host* (*nb*: I have not tested this) you could then use `zfs send` to transfer the whole filesystem to your NAS.

This [core utils bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2011-02/msg00056.html) may shed some light on the state of user and operating system level tools on Linux. Arguably the filesystem level `crtime` field of an inode *should* be difficult to change. While ZFS **on FreeBSD** "supports" `crtime`, the state of low level filesystem debugging tools on FreeBSD might not have kept pace in earlier releases (*cf.* the [`zdb`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zdb&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11-current&arch=default&format=html) manual page). Are you sure you want to "set" (or reset) inode creation times?  Or do you want to preserve them after they have been set on a system that already supports them?

On a FreeBSD system if you `stat` a file stored on a ZFS dataset you will often notice that the `crtime` field of the file is set to the same time as the `ctime` field. This is likely because the application that wrote the file did not have access to library and kernel functions required to set `crtime` at the time the file was "born" and its inode entries were created. There are examples of applications / libraries that try to preserve `crtime` at the application level such as [`libarchive(3)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=archive) (see also: [`archive_entry_atime(3)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=archive_entry_atime)) and gracefully handle inode creation if the archive is restored on a filesystem that does not support the `crtime` field. But that might not be relevant in your case.

As you might imagine, there are a lot of applications that write files to filesystems ... especially with Unix/POSIX systems where "everything is a file".  I'm not sure if older applications would need to be modified or recompiled to support those fields, or whether they would pick them up transparently from the host system's C libraries. Applications being used on older FreeBSD releases or on a Linux system without ext4 could be made to run in compatibility mode on an up to date OS, for example, but whether they would properly handle the time fields is a good question.

For me running this little script as `sh birthtime_test` confirms that file creation times are "turned on" on my FreeBSD systems (all of which use ZFS post `v28` *i.e.* with feature flags):

```
#!/bin/sh
#birthtime_test
uname -r 
if [ -f new_born ] ; then rm -f new_born ; fi

touch new_born 
sleep 3 
touch -a new_born
sleep 3 
echo "Hello from new_born at:" >> new_born 
echo `date` >> new_born
sleep 3 
chmod o+w new_born

stat -f "Name:%t%N
Born:%t%SB
Access:%t%Sa
Modify:%t%Sm 
Change:%t%Sc" new_born

cat new_born
```

**Output:**

```
9.2-RELEASE-p10
Name:   new_born
Born:   May  7 12:38:35 2015
Access: May  7 12:38:38 2015
Modify: May  7 12:38:41 2015 
Change: May  7 12:38:44 2015
Hello from new_born at:
Thu May 7 12:38:41 EDT 2015
```

(NB: the `chmod` operation "changes" but does not "modify" the file contents - this is what the `echo` command does by adding content to the file. See the `touch` manual page for explanations of the `-m` and `-a`  flags).

This is the oldest FreeBSD release I have access to right now. I'd be curious to know how far back in the release cycle FreeBSD is able handle this (on ZFS or UFS2 file systems). I'm pretty sure this has been a feature for quite a while now. There are also OSX and Linux versions of ZFS that it would be useful to know about regarding this feature.

**Just one more thing ...**

Here is an especially nice feature for simple "forensics". Say we want to send our `new_born` file back to when time began, back to the leap second  that never happened and when - in a moment of timeless time - Unix was born ... :-) <sup>**1**</sup>. We can just change the date using `touch -d` and everyone will think `new_born` is old and wise, right?

**Nope:**

```
~/ % touch -d "1970-01-01T00:00:01" new_born                
~/ % stat -f "Name:%t%N   
Born:%t%SB
Access:%t%Sa
Modify:%t%Sm
Change:%t%Sc" new_born
Name:   new_born
Born:   May  7 12:38:35 2015
Access: Jan  1 00:00:01 1970
Modify: Jan  1 00:00:01 1970 
Change: May  7 13:29:37 2015
```

It's always more truthful to actually *be* as young as you look :-)

Time and Unix - a subject both practical and poetic: after all, what is "change"; and what does it mean to "modify" or "create" something? Thanks for your great post Silvio - I hope it lives on and gathers useful answers.

---

You can improve and generalize your question if you can be more specific about your requirements for preserving, setting, archiving of file timestamp fields. Don't get me wrong: this is a very good question and it will continue to get up votes for a long time.

You might take a look at Dylan Leigh's presentation [Forensic Timestamp Analysis of ZFS](http://www.bsdcan.org/2014/schedule/track/Security/464.en.html) or even contact Dylan for clues on how to access `crftime` information.

See also: [Extending The Sleuth Kit and its underlying model for pooled storage file system forensic analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287617301901)

---

[1] There was a legend that claimed in the beginning, seconds since long (SSL) ago was  never less than `date -u -j -f "%Y-%m-%d:%T" "1970-01-01:00:00:01" "+%s"` because of a leap second ...

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try to contact Dylan Leigh.  While reading the crtime is easy under ZFS (stat reports it), the challenge is to set it.

Comment: Yes. FreeBSD has had birthtime/crtime for a long time (on UFS2 as well I believe) so `stat` will show this. You will notice most often the `crtime` is the same as `ctime` because applications creating files aren't always able to access library and kernel functions necessary to set `crtime` at the "birthtime" of the inode.

Comment: Thank you G. Cito for your expanded answer.  I haven't yet got a solution but I've awarded the bounty.  (Sorry it's a miserly one -- I'm new to this group and at the time I only had 99 points because someone had actually downvoted the question!)

Comment: Wow thanks - I thought the bounty had expired. Cheers.

Comment: Cito - you might modify the 1st paragraph of your answer, because pax -pe doesn't preserve birth time or change time.  (man pax says:  ``Preserve everything'', the user ID, group ID, file mode   bits, file access time, and file modification time. )  Thanks for introducing me to pax, though. (I might also point out a tiny typo: it's cf. not c.f. -- it comes from a single word, latin "confer", meaning "compare".)

Comment: Yeah. I was hoping there might be an updated/modern/extended version of `pax` (or even `cpio`) where `-e`  meant "everything the host system can store".  From the state of the standard gnu-coreutils (and to an extent the BSD tools as well) one might infer that the intent is to leave the `crtime` field hidden except for dedicated file system debugging tools.

Comment: Regarding your "Are you sure" question: What I want is pretty much what the question says: transfer the file preserving crtime.  In looking for a tool to *set* crtime I'm merely acknowledging the fact that none of the replication tools known to me offer an option to preserve crtime.  They always leave the file as if newly created.

Comment: @Silvio: Yes, changing the birth date of an existing file is possible.
Had to be because the script starts with creating one, so it acts upon an existing file.

Comment: Has there been any update on this 5 years later? Web searches seem to all show old results, and as if no one is asking this any more. Yet, I couldn't find a working solution.

Comment: @Silvio Thanks for pointing that out - fixed it. _cf._ _e.g._

Comment: @sam-sirry Work is ongoing _cf._ [Extending The Sleuth Kit and its underlying model for pooled storage file system forensic analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287617301901) - but it seems FS forensics and metadata is a rather recondite area of research.