# How to set creation times in Linux?

Tags: python, linux

`utime` only modifies accessed and modified times. Is there a way to do modify the creation/birth time with Python?
Filesystem is ZFS if that matters.

Comment: [How can I set file creation times in ZFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29906359/5160244) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 0):

You want `touch` functionality, and it's available in the `os` module using `utime()`.

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.utime, and also
[Implement touch using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python)

Comment: But utime only supports modification and accessed times, not birth/creation times.